# How can I measure the safeness of a price feed in Chainlink?

Tags: bsc, chainlink, trust

I want to know how to measure the safeness of [a special price feed](https://market.link/feeds/7e531aa9-f45f-4f35-af15-d500c402942d).

As far as I understand, [this price feed](https://market.link/feeds/7e531aa9-f45f-4f35-af15-d500c402942d) is not the official price feed of Chainlink in BSC (based on documents). Also, [its nodes](https://market.link/feeds/7e531aa9-f45f-4f35-af15-d500c402942d/nodes) are not verified and all of them are unknown. Does this mean that the price feed is not safe? Because all of those nodes can be under the control of a single source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feed is actually a Chainlink official feed, it's just not published yet in the docs. Market.link monitors and automatically adds any new feeds it finds, hence why all details (nodes etc) aren't updated yet.

Any multi-oracle feed you find on market.link that uses the 'Offchain Aggregator' (as can be seen in the feed header details) would be a Chainlink official feed because community members running their own OCR feeds aren't yet supported (for now)